# POST method not getting called

Tags: java, spring

Here is my Spring controller:

```
@Controller
public class ReportsController {

  @RequestMapping(value = "/reports.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String getReportsPage(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) {
    map.addAttribute("searchCriteria", new SearchCriteria());
    return "reports";
  }

  @RequestMapping(value = "/reports.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  public String generateReport(@ModelAttribute SearchCriteria searchCriteria, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ModelMap map) {
    log.info(searchCriteria.toString());
    return "reports";
  }

}
```

and here is the form in my JSP file:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="searchCriteria" class="form-inline">
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="startDate">Start Date</label>
 <form:input path="startDate" />
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="endDate">End Date</label>
  <form:input path="endDate" />
</div>
<button type="submit">Generate Report</button>
</form:form>
```

I've tried adding `method` and `action` to the `form` tag and setting them to `post` and `http://bjpeter.company.com:8080/appName/reports.html`, respectively, but the POST method does not get called.

The GET method gets called whenever I go to that page, which is what I want, but the POST method in my controller is not called when I submit the form, and a blank page is returned.

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly set an action on the form.
Check this:
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_mvc_form_handling_example.htm

Then it will work. Something like this:

```
<form:form method="POST" action="/reports">
```

Also, you need to specify a View Resolver, to configure prefix and suffix, read the tutorial from the link.